# ng build --prod If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, production

We're running into an error when building our Angular 5 project with the --prod flag. The reported error is:

```
"[id].[chunkhash:20].chunk.js 
 If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string"
```

The project builds / runs fine in dev. Adding prod specific flags to the dev build works as well (eg --aot=true --sourcemaps=false ... ) which seems to suggest may be problem with UglifyJS.

Looking around for the error, we've found suggestions to downgrade node (currently running v8.9.4) but this is not an option. We've also looked into other causes but none of them worked out.

Any suggestions / recommendations are highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?